# Is there a "screw sense" glyph available in some LaTeX package?

Tags: symbols

I wonder if any LaTeX package provides a glyph for the two screw senses, something like:

[image: right-handed screw sense] and [image: left-handed screw sense]

(compare §II.8 of Schouten: *Tensor Analysis for Physicists*, Dover 2nd ed., 1989).

I've searched the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for "screw", "right-hand", "gyr", and similar, but found nothing.

Or does anyone have a suggestion to make these symbols easily available? For the moment I'm using the macro `\dextro` defined as

```
\newcommand*{\dextro}{\includegraphics[totalheight=\heightof{O}]{screw-sense_posi.png}}
```

and a similar `\laevo` as surrogates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A just-do-it-yourself solution with the `hobby` TikZlibrary.

If you prefer a rounded tail you can add `\filldraw[black] (.1,.85) circle (1.8pt);` to the definition of `\mydx`, as JuoleV pointed out, or use an appropriate node like in `\jdx`.

For creating the gap, you can use the option `[blank=soft]`, like in `\gapdx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, arrows.meta,bending}

\newcommand*{\dextro}{\includegraphics[totalheight=\heightof{O}]{screw-sense_posi.png}}

\newcommand*{\laevo}{\includegraphics[totalheight=\heightof{O}]{screw-sense_neg.png}}

\newcommand*{\mydx}[1][1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, xscale=#1]
\draw[black, -{To[angle=90:.3cm 1,length=9mm, flex'=.86]}, line width=4pt] (.1,.85) to [curve through={(.79,.18) .. (1.45,.7) .. (1.2,1.6) .. (.9,1.6) .. (1.9,1.6)}]
(2.1,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*{\jdx}[1][1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, xscale=#1]
\draw[black, -{To[angle=90:.3cm 1,length=9mm, flex'=.86]}, line width=4pt] (.1,.85) to [curve through={(.79,.18) .. (1.45,.7) .. (1.2,1.6) .. (.9,1.6) .. (1.9,1.6)}]
(2.1,2.5);
\node[circle, minimum width=4pt, fill=black,
  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (.1,.85) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*{\gapdx}[1][1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, xscale=#1]
\draw[black, -{To[angle=90:.3cm 1,length=9mm, flex'=.86]}, line width=4pt] (.1,.85) to [curve through={(.79,.18) .. (1.45,.7) 
(1.48,.8) .. 
([blank=soft]1.43,1.4)
.. (1.2,1.6) .. (.9,1.6) .. (1.9,1.6)}]
(2.1,2.5);
\node[circle, minimum width=4pt, fill=black,
  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (.1,.85) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\newcommand*{\mydextro}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\mydx}}

\newcommand*{\mylaevo}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\mydx[-1]}}

\newcommand*{\jdextro}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\jdx}}

\newcommand*{\jlaevo}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\jdx[-1]}}

\newcommand*{\gapdextro}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\gapdx}}

\newcommand*{\gaplaevo}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{O}}{\gapdx[-1]}}

\begin{document}
Your PNGs: 

screw-sense\_posi.png \includegraphics
{screw-sense_posi.png} 
screw-sense\_neg.png \includegraphics
{screw-sense_neg.png}

\vspace{10pt}My TikZpictures: 

\verb|\mydx|: \mydx
\verb|\mydx[-1]|: \mydx[-1]

\vspace{10pt}Your commands:
\verb|\dextro|: \dextro ~
\verb|\laevo|: \laevo

\vspace{10pt}My commands:
\verb|\mydextro|: \mydextro ~
\verb|\mylaevo|: \mylaevo

\vspace{10pt}Or, if you prefer a rounded tail:

\verb|\jdx|: \jdx
\verb|\jdx[-1]|: \jdx[-1]

\vspace{10pt}\verb|\jdextro|: \jdextro ~
\verb|\jlaevo|: \jlaevo

With gap:
\verb|\gapdx|: \gapdx
\verb|\gapdx[-1]|: \gapdx[-1]

\vspace{10pt}\verb|\gapdextro|: \gapdextro ~
\verb|\gaplaevo|: \gaplaevo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing as usual! I have one small suggestion: The tail of the symbol should be more rounded, i.e. adding a simple line like `\filldraw[black] (.1,.85) circle (1.8pt);` to the definition of `\mydx`.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks, I added a rounded version with a node because it appears better on my pdf viewer.

Comment: Hi CarLaTeX, this looks great! I have two questions:

1. Regarding compilation time and final file size, is using tikz more convenient than embedding tiny images as I've been doing?

2. In your solution would it be possible to introduce a little gap in the curved arrow, as shown in the updated text of my question?

Cheers!

Comment: PS: the gap in my pictures is a little too large. The purpose of a little gap, as you probably guessed, is to show more clearly that the final part of the arrow goes above the initial part.

Comment: @pglpm Yes, it's possible, no time now, I'll update my answer asap. Regarding compilation time, TikZ is slower but you can create a standalone pdf with the gliph and include that one. How many times have you got this symbol in your document?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you! I'd like to see the update when you have time; have accepted your answer anyway. The pdf idea is good. I don't know yet how often the symbol will appear; likely 20–50 times. I'll mention your help in the acknowledgements of the paper, if that's OK for you.

Comment: @CarLaTeX It'd be useful to add an entry "screw sense" with your solution in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List. I'm sure other people are interested in it.

Comment: @pglpm You're very kind, I'd be proud of it. I think till 20 symbols there are no compilation time problems, for more you should try... My solution isn't a real gliph I don't think it deservers to be added in the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" :)

Comment: @pglpm For the version of the glyph with the gap, see my renewed answer.