# How to draw twisted cuves?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner with TikZ, so excuse me if my question is too stupid.

Does anybody know how to draw twists with overcrossing/undercrossing like this one:

[image]

I know how to decorate the curves, my difficulty is to get the overcrossings and kink.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a knots library for tikz?

Comment: have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3

Comment: `hobby` library could be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475298/problem-with-round-cap-arrow-tip-and-blank-soft-option-from-hobby-tikz-librar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rubout` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495715/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rubout/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{rubout/.cd,#1},
 decoration={show path construction,
      curveto code={
       \draw [white,line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/line width}+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/halo}] 
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)  ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast); 
       \draw [line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/line width},shorten <=-0.1pt,shorten >=-0.1pt] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);  
      }}},rubout/.cd,line width/.initial=2pt,halo/.initial=0.5pt]
 \draw[rubout={line width=2pt,halo=1pt},decorate,looseness=2.5] 
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,2) to[out=-90,in=-90] (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is a "double" path option that is easier than this, but I am not sure.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Try `\fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,4);
 \draw[double=black,draw=white] 
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,2) to[out=-90,in=-90] (0,4);` so it does not work because the full path is drawn at once. If you were to split it into two stretches by hand, `\draw[double=black,draw=white] 
   (0,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,2);
  \draw[double=black,draw=white]  (1,2) to[out=-90,in=-90] (0,4);`, it would work again. It is presumably a matter of taste which option is simpler.

Comment: Thanks, that explains my confusion.

Comment: Thank you very  much to all of you for the help! I wish I could choose the answers of all, but this is technically impossible. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `knots` package (included in [spath3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3)).

The `\draw` and `\path` commands are replaced by `\strand` and must be included in the `knot` environment.

There is a `draft` mode that allows you to highlight intersections.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}


Two examples from the knots package manual (p 9):


\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{knot}[consider self intersections,draft mode=crossings]
\strand (0,0) .. controls +(3,1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
\end{knot}

\begin{knot}[xshift=3cm,consider self intersections=no splits,draft mode=crossings]
\strand (0,0) .. controls +(3,1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
\end{knot}

\end{tikzpicture}

The final result is:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[xshift=6cm,consider self intersections,draft mode=off]
\strand (0,0) .. controls +(3,1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}

A figure similar to yours is:

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{knot}[consider self intersections=no splits,draft mode=off]
\strand (0,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (2,-4) .. (2,-3)..controls (2,-2) and (0,-2)..(0,-5);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!