# Tikz : self intersection not recognized in knots library of spath3

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

I have troubles with self intersections in the knots library.
Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc,knots}    

%set default length and width parameters
\def\x{.7}
\def\y{1}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true]
   \strand (0,-\y) .. controls +(0,0) 
      .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,\x/3) and +(0,\x/3) 
      .. (\x/2,0) .. controls +(0,-\x/3) and +(0,-\x/3) 
      .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,0) .. (0,\y);
  \end{knot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this graph
[image: self_intersection]
The self intersection of the loop is not detected by knots. Is there a way to fix this ?

**Edit:**
It somehow has to do  with the *end tolerance* parameter. Depending on it knots detect one or several intersections at the crossing.
The following pictures are taken for *end tolerance* = 0.066 and 0.01.
[image: self_intersection_2]
[image: self_intersection_2_1]
[image: self_intersection_3]
[image: self_intersection_3_1]
Which is still somewhat strange because I would have expected something of the form
[image: self_intersection_3]
This last picture I only managed to create by manually splitting the loop into two strands.

Comment: Because the knots package splits the path into components, it is best practice to keep the intersections away from the ends of the defining pieces.  If you want that *exact* picture then I see that that's not possible, in which case AndréC's answer is probably the best you'll get.  But if you're prepared to deviate very slightly from that picture, a more robust solution is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it is the `end tolerance` parameter that is at stake. But, I redefined your path because its departure and arrival use uselessly beziers curves to draw straight lines. This way I get the result you want.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc,knots}    

%set default length and width parameters
\def\x{.7}
\def\y{1}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{knot}[consider self intersections,end tolerance=.01pt,
  %draft mode=crossings
  ]
   \strand (0,-\y) %.. controls +(0,0) <-- useless beziers curve
      %.. 
      --(0,0) .. controls +(0,\x/3) and +(0,\x/3) 
      .. (\x/2,0) .. controls +(0,-\x/3) and +(0,-\x/3) 
      .. (0,0) %.. controls +(0,0) .. <- useless beziers curve
       --(0,\y);
  \end{knot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

LoopSpace [explained very well what the issue is, and how to fix it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514512/tikz-self-intersection-not-recognized-in-knots-library-of-spath3#comment1301136_514512). Here I'd like to draw your attention to [an alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495715/121799), which has been used in [a very similiar application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502675/194703). This alternative is by no means "better" than, or even comparable to, the `knots` package. The reason why I am mentioning it here is that it gives a rather reasonable output without the need modify your path, or to tune parameters.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rubout/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{rubout/.cd,#1},
 decoration={show path construction,
      curveto code={
       \draw [white,line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/line width}+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/halo}] 
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)  ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast); 
       \draw [line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rubout/line width},shorten <=-0.1pt,shorten >=-0.1pt] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);  
      }}},rubout/.cd,line width/.initial=0.6pt,halo/.initial=0.6pt]
  \def\x{.7}
  \def\y{1}
  \draw[rubout,decorate] (0,-\y) .. controls +(0,0) 
      .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,\x/3) and +(0,\x/3) 
      .. (\x/2,0) .. controls +(0,-\x/3) and +(0,-\x/3) 
      .. (0,0) .. controls +(0,0) .. (0,\y);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't come across the `rubout` decoration before.  It is a "cheap" version of what the knots package does, in that the knots package can handle earlier parts of the path rubbing out later parts, and it can handle more complicated situations, such as when a component of the path goes over itself.  But for when it works, this looks a useful technique.

Comment: @LoopSpace Yes, I agree that this is by no means comparable in scope, but there are applications where this thingy does the job.

Comment: Absolutely!  I didn't mean "cheap" in a negative way.  The knots package can take its time finding the intersections so if the strand is drawn correctly first time then this can be a quick way to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers !
Following the suggestion of Loop Space I created a more stable variant by slightly deviating from the initial picture. I also realized that, for this picture, using `arc` instead of beziers curves keeps the code more readable, but that's just taste I guess.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,knots}
% basic distances for tikz
\def\y{1}
\def\r{-.2}

\begin{document}        
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{knot}[consider self intersections, end tolerance=1pt]
      \strand (0,-\y) to (0,0) arc (0:90:\r) arc (90:270:\r*.6) arc (270:360:\r)  
                      to (0,\y);
    \end{knot}
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: loop]

Comment: +1 but I would recommend replacing \x and \y by some other macros, in particular if you load calc.